# LinkedIn API with MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, linkedin-jsapi

After logging in with the `accounts-linkedIn` package, how can I use the rest of the API to get the user profile for instance.

What I tried is, after loading the LinkedIn librairy like this :

```
$.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true", function success() {
    IN.init({
        api_key: 'XXXXXXX'
    });
});
```

I fetch for the user profile like this :

```
`IN.User.Profile('me')`
```

But I get a message saying that the user is not loggedin. And if I do `IN.User.Authorize()` it works but I am logged a second time with the popup screen which doesn't make sens.

What should I do to have my meteor login sync with the LinkedIn lib ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the user profile, is Meteor.user() not enough ?